# Possibility of a powerful Siberia invading through the far East

Tags: geography, geopolitics

I am trying to imagine a scenario in which a large, powerful and densely populated country in a far more hospitable Northern Asia invades throughout East and Southeast Asia in a similar fashion to Japan, would this invasion be feasible like Japan did? The country has a population similar to this of the United States and military capacities similar to Russia, has direct access to the Pacific ocean, this is set in around 2040, but military capacities of the world's countries are the same as today in real life.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138913/discussion-on-question-by-bangerblade-possibility-of-a-powerful-siberia-invading).

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, we have the following situation:

- The year is 2040, but military capabilities are much as they are in 2022, with one exception.
- There is a powerful country in Northern Asia (Siberia?). This country is not part of Russia, and has not been part of Russia in recent memory. It is considerably more hospitable than the real Siberia.

Assume that "powerful" means a military capability somewhere between Russia, China, and the US. And also not permanently allied to any one of the three. It would have to be a nuclear power, but considering the land borders it would also have a ground and air force with strong defensive capabilities. The needs of your story add strong offensive capabilities.

This fictional country turns old-style imperialist and wants to conquer large parts of South Asia -- that is, Indochina, Indonesia, possibly even India. Several problem with that:

- China would see this move as a geostrategic threat. As soon as the fictional country starts developing the *capabilities* to strike south, China would look for options to counter it, possibly including a much more robust nuclear force.
- The US would also see the move as a geostrategic threat. It might develop a formal alliance system much like NATO in the Pacific. On the other hand, there might not be a NATO in the Atlantic area if the Soviets-without-the-newcomer suffered more in WWII and posed less of a threat to Europe afterwards.
- China and the US might ally against this aggressive fictional state.
- Tripwire deployments from either superpower could create a Cold-War-style MAD.

Summary: With 3-4 superpowers and near-superpowers, any one trying to greatly expand their sphere of influence will be countered by the others.

Comment: "On the other hand, there might not be a NATO in the Atlantic area if the Soviets-without-the-newcomer suffered more in WWII" oof! having a hard time trying to imagine how they could have suffered more than they did (what with the combined effects of the pre war revolution, WW2 itself and the activities of the early soviet regimes, whole lot of purges in among those), it's a big country, short of near entire 'depopulation' I'm not entirely sure how they could have been weakened militarily and economically more than they were? kind of curious what you were thinking might have done the trick :)

Comment: @Pelinore, without the Siberian divisions, Moscow might have been overrun. The US/UK allies might have had to do more to defeat Germany, and their troops might have had to liberate much of central and eastern Europe, meeting the Soviets at the Don and not at the Elbe. But that's just one **possible** alternate history from this ill-defined point of departure.

Comment: An interesting thought, ta 

Comment: @
Pelinore Russia itself is not a big, rich country, nor a powerful one.  It is equivalent to the American state of California in population and GDP.  The current Russia got all of its power and influence through the former USSR, and the contribution of all of the other now independent countries like East Germany, Poland, Czechoslovakia, Ukraine. Countries it gained when America sat back at the end of the war and let Russia take them over. Russia is now coasting on the wealth generation it HAD, but has now LOST. Had America not allowed Russia to gain these WE republics,  NATO would not exist.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond, I don't believe the second part is historically accurate. The Soviet Union replaced the Czarist *Empire*, which had started to form long before America was in position to allow or disallow anything.

Comment: Correct about Czarist Empire right up to just after Napoleon. However, the Crimean War 1853-56 demonstrated the ineffectiveness and decay of this empire. Russia was stuck in 17th century serfdom. Lenin realized this and pulled Russia out of the Great War. At the end of WWll, America wanted Russia's help in defeating Japan (instead of Russia joining with Japan), and bought Russia's agreement with East Germany and the Eastern European countries. American-funded Lend Lease Act made Russia powerful https://ru.usembassy.gov/world-war-ii-allies-u-s-lend-lease-to-the-soviet-union-1941-1945/

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond, there is the quip that Hitler was defeated by British courage, American industry, and Russian blood. Don't short-sell them.